# Rotate image like wheel Animation and which stops at random position

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I am creating a game in which the dice action is shows in a circle.When user clicks on the wheel it rotates and stop at random position.
I search and found some code which I tried to implement like:-

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"RotationAnimation" context:nil];
 CALayer *myLayer = diceCircle.layer;
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotationAnimation;
    fullRotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotationAnimation .fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
   // fullRotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angle];

    fullRotationAnimation.duration = 0.5;          // speed for the rotation. Smaller number is faster
    fullRotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1;  // number of times to spin. 1 = once
    [myLayer addAnimation:fullRotationAnimation forKey:@"360"];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

angle is coming from:-

```
-(IBAction)diceButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    float angle=arc4random()%360;
    NSLog(@"%f",angle);
    float rad=radians(angle);
    NSLog(@"%f",rad);
    [self rotateDiceMethod:rad];
}
```

But the wheels stop at same position everytime and also does not always animate.Please suggest me some approach or sample code for implementing the required functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused; is the top piece of code (the code for the animation) enclosed in the `rotateDeviceMethod:`?

Answer (score 0):

It's my old code for the same task:

```
CGFloat randValue= arc4random() % 10;
self.angleRotate =  (randValue+30);
CABasicAnimation *spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
spinAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.angle];
spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.angle+self.angleRotate];
spinAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
spinAnimation.cumulative = YES;
spinAnimation.additive = YES;
spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
spinAnimation.delegate = self;
spinAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
             functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.arrow.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
```

and when rotation is stopped

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)spinAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    self.angle += self.angleRotate;
    while (self.angle >= M_PI*2.0) {
        self.angle -=  M_PI*2.0;
    }
    NSLog(@"angleRotate value is: %f", self.angleRotate);
    NSLog(@"angle value is: %f", self.angle);
    self.angleRotate = 0;
}
```